# Count Jobs Submitted After Every Hour

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to get the number of jobs that were executed after every hour in Oracle sql.

I have come up with a query to truncate the date to the nearest hour. I'm at a loss on how to write a query that counts the "Job No" occurrences after every hour beginning from midnight.

So far this is my output representing only three columns in the query.

```
Job No  DateTime            TruncDate
2830161 11/06/2019 00:04:21 11/06/2019 00:00:00
2830162 11/06/2019 00:04:38 11/06/2019 00:00:00
2830163 11/06/2019 00:05:57 11/06/2019 00:00:00
2830164 11/06/2019 00:06:18 11/06/2019 00:00:00
2830168 11/06/2019 01:29:03 11/06/2019 01:00:00
2830169 11/06/2019 01:29:39 11/06/2019 01:00:00
2830170 11/06/2019 01:30:07 11/06/2019 01:00:00
2830175 11/06/2019 01:37:33 11/06/2019 01:00:00
2830186 11/06/2019 02:52:04 11/06/2019 02:00:00
2830193 11/06/2019 03:22:02 11/06/2019 03:00:00
2830194 11/06/2019 03:22:40 11/06/2019 03:00:00
2830199 11/06/2019 03:45:08 11/06/2019 03:00:00
2830201 11/06/2019 04:21:09 11/06/2019 04:00:00
2830202 11/06/2019 04:21:25 11/06/2019 04:00:00
2830203 11/06/2019 04:47:30 11/06/2019 04:00:00
2830204 11/06/2019 04:47:48 11/06/2019 04:00:00
2830205 11/06/2019 07:13:43 11/06/2019 07:00:00
2830206 11/06/2019 07:14:55 11/06/2019 07:00:00
2830207 11/06/2019 07:39:02 11/06/2019 07:00:00
2830211 11/06/2019 07:54:52 11/06/2019 07:00:00
2830212 11/06/2019 08:00:50 11/06/2019 08:00:00
2830213 11/06/2019 08:00:53 11/06/2019 08:00:00
2830214 11/06/2019 08:01:06 11/06/2019 08:00:00


SELECT "Job No", "Submit_Date", "Submit_Time", 
       TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("Submit_Date", 'MM-DD-YYYY') || ' ' 
       || "Submit_Time", 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS Datetime,
       TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("Submit_Date", 'MM-DD-YYYY') || ' ' 
       || "Submit_Time", 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH' ) AS truncDate
  FROM VW_SUBMITTEDJOBS 
 ORDER BY "Submit_Date" DESC;
```

I want to achieve something of this sort...

```
COUNT("Job No") or (*) 
 FROM VW_SUBMITTEDJOBS 
WHERE TruncDate BETWEEN 11/06/2019 00:00:00 AND 11/06/2019 01:00:00
```

Im expecting 4 as the answer as per the output above, then

`11/06/2019 01:00:00 AND 11/06/2019 02:00:00`  to show 4 ,

`11/06/2019 02:00:00 AND 11/06/2019 03:00:00`  to show 1

and so forth

Comment: Why on earth do you store date and time values as string?

Comment: in the JD edwards table am querying there are two separate columns for date and time stored as numeric values in julian form. I have formated and concatenated the two and stored it as date in my view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate by `HH24` argument :

```
SELECT TRUNC(Submit_Date,'HH24') as Submit_Date, COUNT(*) as "Count"
  FROM VW_SUBMITTEDJOBS
 GROUP BY TRUNC(Submit_Date,'HH24') 
 ORDER BY Submit_Date DESC;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/LLDZ34723)</kbd>

or explicit formatting by `to_char()` after applying `trunc()` :

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Submit_Date,'HH24'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') as "Submit Date", 
       COUNT(*) as "Count"
  FROM VW_SUBMITTEDJOBS
 GROUP BY TO_CHAR(TRUNC(Submit_Date,'HH24'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') 
 ORDER BY "Submit Date" DESC;
```

Comment: getting the error .. ORA-32040: recursive WITH clause must use a UNION ALL operation. I don't know how you are getting the SELECT 2830161, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 00:04:21','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL statements

Comment: have already you tried the demo @E.Ogony ? Sample data already has been created by UNION ALL clauses ...

Comment: If you mean formatting was different than the data literal within`TO_TIMESTAMP('11/06/2019 01:29:03','MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')` e.g. slash vs. dash, that's not problem but anyway I fixed in the Demo due to ANSI standard as `TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-11-06 01:29:03','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')` @E.Ogony .

Comment: the demo is returning the right information. But how do i implement it if I want the selects plus the union to come from the database?. Thanks for helping.

Comment: the challenge im having is retrieving the selects statements in the CTE from the database.

Comment: Consider [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5612dd245d04381df0a4789ee8822864)

Comment: could you post an example that doesn't have hard-coded values

Comment: what do you mean by hard-coding @E.Ogony ?

Comment: i've just confirmed the values returned are accurate. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

You can truncate the datetime column in your where clause. For example to get all the jobs started between 1 AM and 2 AM:

```
with vw_submittedjobs(jobno, datetime) AS
(
SELECT 2830161, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 00:04:21','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830162, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 00:04:38','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830163, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 00:05:57','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830164, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 00:06:18','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830168, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 01:29:03','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830169, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 01:29:39','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830170, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 01:30:07','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830175, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 01:37:33','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830186, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 02:52:04','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830193, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 03:22:02','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830194, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 03:22:40','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830199, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 03:45:08','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830201, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 04:21:09','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830202, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 04:21:25','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830203, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 04:47:30','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830204, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 04:47:48','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830205, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 07:13:43','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830206, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 07:14:55','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830207, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 07:39:02','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830211, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 07:54:52','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830212, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 08:00:50','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830213, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 08:00:53','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2830214, TO_DATE('11/06/2019 08:01:06','MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT 
  COUNT(jobno) job_count
  FROM vw_submittedjobs
  WHERE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(datetime,'HH24'),'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') = '11/06/2019 01:00:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use the `Submit_Date` and `Submit_Time` in the `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
SELECT
    DATETIME,
    COUNT(1) AS "NUMBER OF JOBS"
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            "Job No",
            TRUNC(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("Submit_Date", 'MM-DD-YYYY')
                          || ' '
                          || "Submit_Time", 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 'HH') AS DATETIME
        FROM
            VW_SUBMITTEDJOBS
        WHERE
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR("Submit_Date", 'MM-DD-YYYY')
                    || ' '
                    || "Submit_Time", 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
                        BETWEEN '11/06/2019 00:00:00' AND '11/06/2019 01:00:00'
    )
GROUP BY
    TRUNC(DATETIME, 'HH');
```